# rails why need other project bundle gems?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, bundler

i have two project,which one called `A` with `Rails` another called `B` just pure `Ruby` code.

when i call `A` controller actions named `do_action` it will call `B` rake tasks such `rake dosomething`

but i got error:

```
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- pry
```

the gem `pry` in `B` Gemfile.

i want to know why rails project `A` will need `B` Gemfiles gems?

i think my linux env probelem? thk

Comment: add require "pry" in application.rb after require 'rails'

Comment: yes, i can do that. it will make project `A` more biger,so i think have best way do it. THK

Comment: have the answer been helpful?

Answer (score 1):

Since you have call to `rake dosomething` to other's project from the specific (first) one, the environment gems will be applied from the first project. So, either:

1. add the *pry* gem dependency into the first project
2. generate the second project, which is in pure ruby, as a gem, and add it as a dependency into **Gemfile** of your *Rails* project as follows:

   ```
   gem 'your_ruby_project_gem', :path => 'path/to/your/ruby/gem/project'
   ```

   The way is for the projects, which are current under a development, i.e. the argument `:path` allows you to change the code under that path, so you *gem* will be also changed without reinstallation. Refer to more the [bundler documentation](http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html). To run the *Rails* project you have to exec as follows:

   ```
   bundle exec rails s
   ```

I prefer the second approach.

Comment: project `B` not just pure ruby code. it's ruby project it will change frequently. i don't want to make it to gem.so have some way?

Comment: @lioooo yes, the proposed *second* way is for the project, which is under development, i.e. argument `:path` allows you to chnage the code under path, so you "gem" will also changed without reinstallation: read here: http://bundler.io/v1.5/gemfile.html